# Prove the solution of von Neumann equation will never stabilize if Hamiltonian and initial density matrix commutes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space, density-operator

Given von Neumann equation 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \rho(t) = -i [H, \rho(t)] = -i e^{-iHt}[H, \rho(0)]e^{iHt}.$$

If we know that $[H, \rho(0)] \neq 0$, how do we prove in details the solution of von Neumann equation will never be stabilized, i.e. $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{d}{dt} \rho(t) \neq 0~?$$

Comment: What do you mean by stability?

Comment: @yuggib It means the density matrix will never approach the steady state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints to the question (v2):

1. First note that the [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) $$\tag{1}||A||~=~||UA||~=~||AU||$$ of an operator $A$ is invariant if we compose with an unitary operator $U$ from either left or right.
2. Therefore $\dot{\rho}(t)$ is not the zero-operator:  $$\tag{2}|| \dot{\rho}(t) || ~=~ || [H, \rho(t)] || ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ || [H, \rho(0)] || ~\neq~ 0. $$